# Input type text is not compatible in IOS

Tags: html, css

I wanted to create a text input in IOS. It seems that `type="text"` is not working on IOS. When I'm typed on the text input, nothing appeared.

```
          <input class="inputs" type="text" maxlength="1" />
```

Comment: The only error I can think of is that pre-HTML5 didn't allow you to use "/>" with input, you needed to end it with just a ">". If your safari is an old version, this could be causing an error, otherwise I have no idea.

Comment: can u write it in the answers @Jeffrey?

Comment: We'll need more info to help with this. Can you tell us which browser you're using (ideally with the version number) and the device you're using to see the problem. Also, we'll probably need to see more of the surrounding code as what you've shown is just the one element, which should work.

Answer (score 1):

This should work on updated browsers, the `maxlength` part for `<input>` is supported in Safari 1.0 as [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp) says

Answer (score 1):

New idea: Are you missing a closing tag somewhere else? This could make it appear that your text input isn't working.

The only error I can think of is that pre-HTML5 didn't allow you to use "/>" with input, you needed to end it with just a ">". If your safari is an old version, this could be causing an error, otherwise I have no idea.